# Java Loop for n integer sum

Tags: java, eclipse

I have problem with the following question:

> Write a program that prompts the user to enter an integer, n. The
>   program will print the following results:
>
> 1. Sum of all even numbers between 1 and n (inclusive)
> 2. Sum of all odd numbers between 1 and n (inclusive)

Here the code I have so far, when I hit run I am getting exponentially large numbers that keep multiplying. I am aware my code is wrong. I dont know what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

```
package assig;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment4_Question1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
int n = in.nextInt();
int evenSum = 0;
int oddSum= 0;

for (int i = 1; 1<=n; i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
    evenSum = evenSum + i;
    } else if (i % 2 != 0){
    oddSum = oddSum + i;
    }
    System.out.println(evenSum);
    System.out.println(oddSum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `1<=n` vs `i<=n`

Comment: Please format your code properly. It's very hard to read without any indentation.

Comment: SInce i am new to this why is my question getting downvoted ?

Comment: Downvotes are based on the question itself, not the person posting it. Questions which are resolved because of a typo are not useful to the community. In the future, you can find typos by creating a [mcve].

Comment: @4castle the question i was intending for is that even if i fix that type the loop is not giving me the evensum and oddsum and i wanted to be pointed in the right direction, just a suggestion or two if that is not much to ask here

Comment: I'm not positive, but are you referring to how the output is shown at each step? To fix that, move the print statements so they aren't inside the curly braces of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You loop is never ending !

```
    for (int i = 1; 1<=n; i++)
```

So you are saying the loop will go infinte if you n is bigger than 1!

```
   for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
```

The difference in here that you loop will go until i reach to n.

Answer (score 0):

You must change :

```
for (int i = 1; 1<=n; i++)
```

to:

```
for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
```